# Getting stuck in view when using Ajax with Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm trying to use Ajax in order to validate if a value of a field already exists in the DB.

urls.py:

```
#App Auxiliares_Tipos:
path('ajax/validar_tipaux/', validar_tipaux),
path('Tipos_de_auxiliares/', tipoAuxi),
```

views.py:

```
def validar_tipaux(request):
    codigo = request.GET.get('codigo', None)
    print(codigo)
    data = {
        'is_taken': TipoAux.objects.filter(codigo__iexact=codigo).exists()
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

`validation.js` is included in my html body.

validation.js:

```
$("#id_codigo").change(function () {
    var tipaux = $(this).val();
    console.log(tipaux);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/validar_tipaux/',
        data: {
            'tipaux': tipaux
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.is_taken) {
                console.log('Existe');
                alert("That value is already taken.");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

id_codigo is the id of the field that I'm checking if exists with Ajax.

The error: it works almost at all, the JavaScript detects changes on `id_codigo` properly (I'm trying to check everything with print/console.log). But it gets stuck in the view `validar_tipaux` where it prints **None** as `codigo`'s value.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending the data as `tipaux` but your view is looking for `codigo`.